# Get Content Controls into results of Search

Tags: office-js

I have create a content control over the word 'here' in the next example sentence:
"This sentence contents a content control here and the rest is normal."
I would like to search the word "here" and to know if exist any content control into the results of search. I have done several examples but the results of the search always are empty of content controls.
Is there any way to do it?
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Please provide code that you've tried and specify what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Already I have found the solution myself :) 
I put here in order to be useful for the rest of community.
I wanted to know if any item into the results of the "search" method contained some content control. I though the next:

1. That I must find inside of every item of the result of "search"
   method, it means, each item of the range collection.
   In this case, for each range only exist one paragraph.
2. I was searching contain control collections inside of each
   paragraph of the each range, inside of the results of "search"
   method"

But I was wrong, the solution was the next:

```
const searchText = 'what_ever_you_want_to_search'
const searchResults = context.document.body.search(searchText, { matchWholeWord: true })
searchResults.load('items')
await context.sync()
for (let index = 0; index < searchResults.items.length; index++) {
    const searchResult = searchResults.items[index]
    const cc = searchResult.parentContentControlOrNullObject
    cc.load('title')
    await context.sync()
    console.log(cc.title)
}
```

It means, that the solution is to check the parentContentControl instead to check if there is a content control collections (with paragraph.contentControls) inside of each paragraph of the each range into the range collection result of the "search" method.

I apologize if I have expresed wrong but the english it is not my native language...jejeje If anyone has some doubt then I would be happy to answer it.

BR